# How to evaluate the following limit of inverse function?

Tags: limits

The value of $$\lim_{x \to \infty} [(x+2)\tan^{-1}(x+2)- x \tan^{-1}x]$$ is?

Comment: "Something you should at least try to determine yourself before asking it here without any details?"

Comment: $\tan^{-1}(\infty)=\pi/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x(\tan^{-1}(x+2)-\tan^{-1}x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\tan^{-1}\frac{x+2-x}{1+x(x+2)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{1+x(x+2)}}{1/x}$$

Now, by LH rule or using series expansion of $\tan ^{-1}y = y - \frac{y^3}{3} + \ldots, \ |y| < 1$, the above limit evaluates to $0$.

Therefore the original limit evaluates to,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} 2\tan^{-1}(x+2) = \pi$$

**Edit**:

$$L_{original} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x(\tan^{-1}(x+2)-\tan^{-1}x) + 2\tan^{-1}(x+2)$$

where the first term $\rightarrow 0$ and the second term $\rightarrow \pi$ which is no more an indeterminate form.

Comment: Where did the $(x+2)$ go at the beginning (you seem to have switched it to be an $x$ in your initial factorization -- why)?

Comment: @ClementC. Check the edit.

Comment: Thanks. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Writting as $$2\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(x+2)\arctan(x+2)-x\arctan(x)}{x+2-x}$$

Let $f(t) = t\arctan t\; \forall t\in \left[x,x+2\right]$ , where $x\rightarrow \infty$

Using $\bf{LMVT}$

$$2\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(x+2)\arctan(x+2)-x\arctan(x)}{x+2-x} = \lim_{c\rightarrow \infty}2f'(c)$$

$$ = 2\lim_{c\rightarrow \infty}\bigg[\cdot \frac{c}{1+c^2}+\arctan c\bigg] = 2\cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \pi$$

Where $c\in \left(x,x+2\right)$